# Putting AirPods in case automatically starts music/video on Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, google-chrome, youtube, airpods

Reproduce:

- Connect AirPods to MacBook
- Start a video in YouTube (using Google Chrome)
- Stop a video in YouTube
- Put AirPods in case
- **Result:** YouTube video automatically starts playing in a couple of seconds

Is it reproducible or is it just something wrong with my setup?

Devices: AirPods, MacBook Pro 2018 (MR932).